# Solr having trouble Querying values containing forward slashes

Tags: solr, solrnet

Trying to query Solr that contains a value with forward slashes. But I keep receiving '0' results even though "/foo/" exists within Solr.

```
var query = Query.Field("tenant_id").Is("/foo/");
var results = solrCore.Query(query);
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on the best way to tackle this issue?

**UPDATE**

Figured it out with SolrNet, very simple fix that made me feel like an idiot...

```
var query = new SolrQuery("tenant_id:\\/retail\\/");
var results = solrCore.Query(query);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `/foo/` is the syntax of a regular expression search in Solr, so depending on your field type and if your library escapes `/`, this can be processed in multiple ways. What is the definition of `tenant_id`? Have you looked at the Solr log to see what the actual query sent to Solr is?

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

**'/'** is now a special character and must be escaped.

```
"\/foo\/"
```

Comment: Nope, still receiving '0' results. What I did: var query = Query.Field("tenant_id").Is("\\/foo\\/");

Comment: Have you tried to use solr UI interface to see results directly?

Comment: I did, and I was able to retrieve the results. But I couldnt figure out why I was having issues with Querying with SolrNet even with the escape characters. Thankfully I figured out the issue. Check my update for details.